# how to add jquery data attributes in rails image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to add the following attribute in my rails `image_tag`

`data-zoom-image`

I tried

```
<%= image_tag @post.uploads.first.upload.url(:medium), data: { :zoom-image => 'test'} %>
```

But throwing syntax error undefined local variable or method image.

How can I add attribute rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:zoom-image` isn't a valid symbol.  You can't have a dash in there.  You want this:

```
data: { zoom_image: 'test'}
```

or this:

```
data: { 'zoom-image' => 'test'}
```

In the both cases, Rails will output `data-zoom-image="test"` into the HTML.